# How to Scrape the IDs and Text relevant to IDs under heading for all the html files of "https://www.drugs.com/"?

Tags: python, nlp

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import requests
import pandas as pd

count = 0
df = []
for i in ['https://www.drugs.com/cons/a-b-otic.html','https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-and-lamivudine-tablets.html']:
    print(i)
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    response2 = requests.get(i)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'html.parser')
    data2 = soup2.findAll('ul',attrs={'class':'ddc-anchor-links'})
    print(data2)
    if len(data2)==0:
        data2 = soup2.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'ddc-toc-content'})
    empty = []
    for div2 in data2:
        link2 = div2.findAll('a')
        for c in link2:
            print(c['href'] +" -- "+c.text.lower())
            empty.append(c['href'].replace('#',''))
        print(empty)

empty.append('moreResources')
aa = {}
for i in range(len(empty)):

    if i < len(empty)-1:
        s1 = str(soup2).find('id="{}"'.format(empty[i]))
        s2 = str(soup2).find('id="{}"'.format(empty[i+1]))
        s3 = str(soup2)[s1:s2]
        if 'uses' in empty:
            s3 = "<h2 " + s3
        else:
            s3= '<a ' + s3 
        aa[empty[i]] = s3
df.append(aa)

df11 = pd.DataFrame(df)
df11
```

Problem : I'm able to extract the content but along with Content, I'm getting all the HTML elements as well. How to eliminate HTMl elements and extract only Text

[image: Output of the website "https://www.drugs.com/cons/a-b-otic.html"]

P.s : There are 2-3 structures of Pages in the website. Another example pages structure is "https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-sulfate-tablets.html"

Comment: Please refer to this before asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What did you try so far to achieve this ? Please post your code.

Comment: @abhishek my output is pretty long, I can't help with it. It's my desired output

Comment: @Ram i've added code

Comment: for getting only text try <tag>.text . replace <tag> with your loop var.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant generalize the scraping which is dedicated for one specific url and source.
now you changed your requirement from one url to another and need a code to scrape both i think its kinda tough but feasible.

none the less try this for your first given url. i.e : https://www.drugs.com/cons/a-b-otic.html

it works for me but cant post the output like you said before its too long.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
import requests as req

url ="https://www.drugs.com/cons/a-b-otic.html"
key_list = []
result = {}
tmp_list = []
try:
  otp = req.get(url,timeout=30)
  if otp.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(otp.text, 'lxml')
    
    name = soup.find('li', {'class':'ddc-breadcrumb-item active'}).find('span').text
    result['Drug Name'] = name
    hrefs = soup.find_all('a',{'class':'ddc-link-no-visited'},href=True)
    for href in hrefs:
      key_list.append(href['href'].replace('#',''))
    print(key_list)

    pr = soup.find('h2', {'id':'uses'}).find_previous()
    
    pre = pr.find_next_siblings()
    
    tmp = []
    add_key = None
    for p in pre: 
      next_tag = p.find_next()
      previous_tag = p.find_previous()    
      if not isinstance(p, NavigableString):
        if p.name == 'h2' and p.get('id') in key_list:
          # get key index 
          key = key_list[key_list.index(p.get('id'))]
          add_key = key
          
        elif (p.name != 'h2'):
          tmp.append(p.text)
        
        if len(tmp) > 0 and add_key is not None and next_tag.name == 'h2':
          result[add_key] = ''.join(tmp)
          tmp.clear()
          add_key = None
        if p.name == 'div' and p.get('id') is 'moreResources':
          break
        
    print(result)
    print(json.dumps(result))
    
  else:
    print('Error in connecting')
except req.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
  print(e)
```

so far if your source contain the these keys:['uses', 'before-taking', 'dosage', 'side-effects'] it will scrape the source for given keys.

Comment: Yes we can do that but it depends upon page source and something unique to identify like previous url have cons it it and this one have pro in it. I think you get the idea.

Comment: Yeah, that has been working very well but the output is not appropriate. If you check for "uses" it has taken content from "before taking" as well. Thanks. 
"https://www.drugs.com/pro/abacavir-sulfate-tablets.html" this has been another page structure present in the website. So, can we make it dynamic so that we can extract for both the URLs? @Abhishek

Comment: understood, like every page is unique but I'm trying to make a function that can get all necessary information from "drugs.com" @Abhishek 
i'm learning NLP and this task is proving difficult

Comment: You can have a function which can do both url , it’s just you have check url before and use of some if conditions will do

Comment: can you re-check the output, it's scrapping some additional text from next "TAG" @Abhishek

Comment: Sure I’ll check it.but exactly where it getting the additional text

Comment: for "Uses"  the text ends "In the U.S., this medicine is available only with your doctor's prescription" with this line. But, the output from function is taking text from "Before Taking" as well and storing it in "Uses".

Comment: Just need some minor adjustments go ahead and try it see if it works, must be with tmp list

Comment: @Flameling you sorted it out yet? i have made different approach to this with not repetitive text. edited the answer try that.

Comment: I tried to sort "tmp = []" but it was extracting more information than what's needed. I think I'll need a day or more, to try out something more

Comment: by sorted i mean figured it out yet.  ive edited the code and now it scrap only what is required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233988/discussion-between-flameling-and-abhishek).